# Declaring diagonal matrices of varying dimension and content

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

Given integers $N$ and $k$, I am trying to construct a set of $N$ diagonal matrices of dimension $N \times N$, defined by

$$H_{k} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2k(k+1)}}\operatorname{diag}(\underbrace{1, 1, \ldots, 1}_{k}, \underbrace{-k}_{(k+1)^{th}\text{ position}}, \underbrace{0, \ldots, 0}_{(N-k-1) 
\text{ zeros}} )$$

(these are Cartan generators of $SU(N)$) using the *Mathematica* command

```
H[k_, N_] := 1/Sqrt[2*k*(k + 1)]*DiagonalMatrix[
              ConstantArray[1, k], -k, ConstantArray[0, (N - k - 1)]
             ]
```

The error I get on trying to find (say) `H[1, 3]` is

> `DiagonalMatrix::dims: Dimension specification {0} should be a positive machine integer or a pair of positive machine integers.`

I think this is because the third `ConstantArray` can get `0` as the second (size) argument. In this case I'd like to tell `DiagonalMatrix` to skip `0`-sized arguments. How do I achieve this?

Comment: H[k_, N_] := 
 1/Sqrt[2*k*(k + 1)]*
  DiagonalMatrix[
   Flatten[{ConstantArray[1, k], -k, ConstantArray[0, (N - k - 1)]}]]

Comment: @egwenesedai, perfect, thank you!

Comment: in the question, -k should be at the k+1 position (not k-th) right? also, if k is allowed to be equal to N then the last `ConstantArray` may not work. In this case, consider use `Table[If[i <= k, 1, If[i == k + 1, -k, 0]], {i, 1, N}]` inside the `DiagonalMatrix`

Comment: @egwenesedai, thanks for your insight. Yes, I fixed the typo in the problem.

Answer (score 1):

egwene's code in the comments works fine, but in implementing something like this, I vastly prefer using `PadRight[]`:

```
CartanH[k_, n_] :=
      DiagonalMatrix[PadRight[Append[ConstantArray[1, k], -k], n]/Sqrt[2 k (k + 1)]]
```

or directly constructing a `SparseArray[]`:

```
CartanH[k_, n_] := With[{d = Sqrt[2 k (k + 1)]}, 
      SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}, {k, k}] -> 1/d, {k, k} + 1 -> -k/d}, {n, n}]]
```